# baselineskip ruins my layout and shifts everything too low

Tags: errors, layout

I have a page consisting of two pieces, each one having two lines to sign on. Its kind of a contract, explaining that I wrote my seminar work by myself.

However, I want the date of the signature to be spaced exactly two lines, however when I add `\\[2\baselineskip]` in the second part - in the same place as in the first part - my layout shifts a lot.

[image]

I want The same spacing as above, but it results in

[image]

My code is

```tex
% Seitenlayout
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, top=20mm, bottom=20mm, right=30mm, left=30mm]{geometry}

% Times New Roman
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{standalone}

\newcommand\tline[2]{$\underset{\text{#1}}{\text{\underline{\hspace{#2}}}}$}

\usepackage[]{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\section*{Erklärung der Selbständigkeit}
Hiermit versichere ich, dass ich die Arbeit selbstständig angefertigt, keine anderen als die angegebenen Hilfsmittel benutzt und die Stellen der Facharbeit, die im Wortlaut oder im wesentlichen Inhalt aus anderen Werken entnommen wurden, mit genauer Quellenangabe kenntlich gemacht habe. Verwendete Informationen aus dem Internet sind der Lehrkraft vollständig im Ausdruck zur Verfügung gestellt worden.\\[2\baselineskip]

\noindent Hannover, den 17.03.2021\\[2\baselineskip]
\tline{(Name)}{4cm}\hspace{4cm}\tline{(Unterschrift)}{4cm}

\vfill
\noindent Hiermit erkläre ich, dass ich damit einverstanden bin, wenn die von mir verfasste Facharbeit der schulinternen Öffentlichkeit zugänglich gemacht wird.\\[2\baselineskip]
\noindent Hannover, den 17.03.2021\\[2\baselineskip]
\tline{(Name)}{4cm}\hspace{4cm}\tline{(Unterschrift)}{4cm}
\vspace{0.5\textheight}

\end{document}
```

Comment: multicols is the wrong environment here. Beside this: show always a small but complete example, that makes it much easier to test solutions.

Comment: Hello @UlrikeFischer thank you for answering. How would I go about it then? Also, you mean with packages and all?

Comment: post something that others can copy and test as is. Here we have to add a lot to even test the code.

Comment: I would write the line simply as `\tline{(Name)}{4cm}\hspace{4cm}\tline{(Unterschrift)}{4cm}`

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. I've included my full setup in the original question, please have a look. / @UlrikeFischer thank you, I've changed to your version. However, my second part still doenst start at 50% of the page height, when I use `\\[2\baselineskip]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need \vfill at the end. And don't add an empty line if you use `\\`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, top=20mm, bottom=20mm, right=30mm, left=30mm]{geometry}

% Times New Roman
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{standalone}

\newcommand\tline[2]{$\underset{\text{#1}}{\text{\underline{\hspace{#2}}}}$}

\usepackage[]{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\section*{Erklärung der Selbständigkeit}
Hiermit versichere ich, dass ich die Arbeit selbstständig angefertigt, keine anderen als die angegebenen Hilfsmittel benutzt und die Stellen der Facharbeit, die im Wortlaut oder im wesentlichen Inhalt aus anderen Werken entnommen wurden, mit genauer Quellenangabe kenntlich gemacht habe. Verwendete Informationen aus dem Internet sind der Lehrkraft vollständig im Ausdruck zur Verfügung gestellt worden.\\[2\baselineskip]
Hannover, den 17.03.2021\\[2\baselineskip]
\tline{(Name)}{4cm}\hspace{4cm}\tline{(Unterschrift)}{4cm}

\vfill
\noindent Hiermit erkläre ich, dass ich damit einverstanden bin, wenn die von mir verfasste Facharbeit der schulinternen Öffentlichkeit zugänglich gemacht wird.\\[2\baselineskip]
Hannover, den 17.03.2021\\[2\baselineskip]
\tline{(Name)}{4cm}\hspace{4cm}\tline{(Unterschrift)}{4cm}

\vfill

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works for me, thank you very much Ulrike!